# django and jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatable

I am using django to build a database that can be viewed over a website.

Before going deep into my project, I built the django app and added a table into my models with only one row of data. Now I am trying to visualise that table using jquery datatables. However, jquery datatables format is not showing. I tried every possible solution I found but nothing is working out yet.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Variant(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    protein_id = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    gene_symbol = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    chromosome = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    variation = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    consequence = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    rs = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    maf = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    phenotype = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    source = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from view_data.models import *

def variants(request):
    queryset = Variant.objects.all()
    return render(request, "variants.html", {"allvars": queryset})
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from view_data import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^variants/', views.variants),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

variants.html

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }} js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }} jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }} jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }} jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("table_id").dataTable();
             });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">    
<table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Variant Type</th>
    <th>Protein Id</th>
    <th>Gene Symbol</th>
    <th>Chromosome</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Variation</th>
    <th>Consequence</th>
    <th>RS Id</th>
    <th>GMAF</th>
    <th>Phenotype</th>
    <th>Source</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for v in allvars %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ v.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.protein_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.gene_symbol }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.chromosome }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.position }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.variation }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.consequence }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.rs }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.maf }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.phenotype }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.source }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The static folder that contains the js and css files is on the same level as my django app (view_data). In settings.py file, I added 'view_data' and 'jquery' to INSTALLED_APPS. I also specify my static files as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

Now when I run the server, I got in the terminal the following lines:

```
[21/Feb/2017 15:33:54] "GET /variants/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1079
[21/Feb/2017 15:33:54] "GET /variants/jquery.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1079
[21/Feb/2017 15:33:54] "GET /variants/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1079
[21/Feb/2017 15:33:54] "GET /variants/jquery.dataTables.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1079
[21/Feb/2017 15:33:54] "GET /variants/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1079
```

But when I check website link, it is showing me the data arranged in rows but with no table formatting at all. May you please help me identifying what I did wrong and how can I fix this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.
EMH

Comment: You may want to post the rendered markup as well.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get it. May you please explain what do you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have forgetten the `#` in `$("table_id").dataTable();`

It should be like:

```
$("#table_id").dataTable();<br>
```

Comment: I have tried it and it is still not showing, thanks for the correction.